# How to configure vite/rollup to exclude firebase-admin from my clientside code?

Tags: typescript, firebase, server-side-rendering, firebase-admin, vite

I've been using this `vite-plugin-ssr`  with firebase functions happily until one day `firebase-admin` bailed on me. My setup was working until I deleted my node modules and reinstalled my dependencies. It seems that `vite` is bundling `firebase-admin` with the client even though there are no imports in clientside code referring to `firebase-admin`, only in the `.page.server.ts` files. How do I specify to `vite` or `rollup`  to not bundle `firebase-admin` into the `dist/client` directory?

I would really appreciate some pointers... I've spent 24hrs + on this one issue and at this point I am considering switching the SSR off, or copying the files to a fresh project. Basically I just want a clean setup with this simple stack:

- firebase functions
- `vite` + SSR (using `vite-plugin-ssr`)
- preact and typescript

```
> vite build "--config" "vite-ssr.config.ts"

node_modules/@firebase/util/node_modules/tslib/tslib.es6.js'fast-crc32c' is imported by fast-crc32c?commonjs-external, but could not be resolved – treating it as an external dependency
transforming (2472) 
✓ 2478 modules transformed.
'default' is not exported by node_modules/firebase/app/dist/index.esm.js, imported by node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.esm.js
file: /Users/mateh/github/control-me/web-app/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.esm.js:1:7
1: import firebase from 'firebase/app';
          ^
```

Things I have tried:

- Updated to the lasest version of all the firebase related dependencies
- Tried enabling `allowSyntheticDefaultImports` in tsconfig, did not make a difference
- manually edit the file in `node_modules` to `import * from '@firebase/app'`. The build will pass this way but the client will not be able to use the `fast-crc32c` module.
- installed `fast-crc32c` module to no avail, there is a generic Object is undefined error somewhere in `firebase-admin` code, obviously it's not meant to be run on the clientside in the browser.
- Both functions and the client has the same set of dependencies. Next, I tried to alias it with rollup so that *only* `firebase` is installed on the clientside package.json and *only* `firebase-admin` is in the serverside functions package.json, issue still persists.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adding this to my `vite` configuration fixed it:

```
build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      external: ['firebase-admin'],
```